# QGIS Install Help: Library Not Loaded / Image Not Found

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, qgis-3

I'm having trouble updating to QGIS 3.4.4. Following install, the program does not open. I have Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed. I also downloaded and installed GDAL 2.3 from https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/. What am I missing?

```
Dyld Error Message:

Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/GEOS
  Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Check the bug reporting page, https://issues.qgis.org/

Comment: I have this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by uninstalling QGIS3, then:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/
mv 3B 3
```

Reinstall QGIS3.

I honestly don't know if there are any negative side-effects if changing the GEOS directory name, but it made QGIS3 work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of renaming the directory, you can simply create a soft link to 3B called 3 like this:

ln -s /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3B /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3

That way any other application that may look for 3B will still find it. There is no need to reinstall QGIS3 either. Just close the error, create the link, and open the app again.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on Jan. 22, 2019. Since then, I re-downloaded the update and installed on Jan. 30 with no problems.

Thank you for the answers!